# File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. (For firebase ml kit)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-mlkit

I have seen some similar questions related to this error. But I wasn't able to solve the problem. **I am using firebase ml kit to recognize text from an image. I have added the google-services.json file to the app directory, but still, I got the same error.** If anyone can solve this issue please let me know.

**I have got the following error:**

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\src\debug\google-services.json
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
E:\Practices\Android Projects\2019\DataFactor\app\google-services.json
```

**My build.gradle for project :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My build.gradle for app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.shakil.com.datafactor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: The Play services plugin disagrees that you put the file in the right place.  It's even telling you the list of places it checked.

Comment: Have you found an answer?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah i found the answer.I misplaced the json file.Try to put the json file in the right directory. I just moved the json file from project level to app level.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered by (I presume) the original poster:
"Yeah i found the answer.I misplaced the json file.Try to put the json file in the right directory. I just moved the json file from project level to app level. – Sakhawat Hossain Oct 22 '19 at 9:30".